# Undefined reference to boost::system::generic_category() although libs are given to g++

Tags: c++, boost, linker

What are the linker flags I'm missing here?

I try to compile this on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and it fails, it works inside a Debian 9 docker image:

```cpp
#include <boost/dll.hpp>

// Trying to compile it with:
// g++ -o program -lboost_filesystem -ldl -lboost_system program.cpp

int main() {
  boost::dll::program_location();
  return 0;
}
```

The error I get is:

```
/tmp/ccKlWUUd.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
program.cpp:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
program.cpp:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
program.cpp:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccKlWUUd.o: In function `boost::system::error_code::error_code()':
program.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6system10error_codeC2Ev[_ZN5boost6system10error_codeC5Ev]+0x17): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccKlWUUd.o: In function `boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(int, std::error_condition const&) const':
program.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost6system14error_category12std_category10equivalentEiRKSt15error_condition[_ZNK5boost6system14error_category12std_category10equivalentEiRKSt15error_condition]+0xb8): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
program.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost6system14error_category12std_category10equivalentEiRKSt15error_condition[_ZNK5boost6system14error_category12std_category10equivalentEiRKSt15error_condition]+0xf3): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/tmp/ccKlWUUd.o: In function `boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(std::error_code const&, int) const':
program.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost6system14error_category12std_category10equivalentERKSt10error_codei[_ZNK5boost6system14error_category12std_category10equivalentERKSt10error_codei]+0xb8): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
program.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost6system14error_category12std_category10equivalentERKSt10error_codei[_ZNK5boost6system14error_category12std_category10equivalentERKSt10error_codei]+0xf3): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
program.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost6system14error_category12std_category10equivalentERKSt10error_codei[_ZNK5boost6system14error_category12std_category10equivalentERKSt10error_codei]+0x1d2): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/tmp/ccKlWUUd.o: In function `boost::dll::detail::report_error(boost::system::error_code const&, char const*)':
program.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3dll6detail12report_errorERKNS_6system10error_codeEPKc[_ZN5boost3dll6detail12report_errorERKNS_6system10error_codeEPKc]+0x2a): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/tmp/ccKlWUUd.o: In function `boost::filesystem::read_symlink(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code&)':
program.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost10filesystem12read_symlinkERKNS0_4pathERNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost10filesystem12read_symlinkERKNS0_4pathERNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x36): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::read_symlink(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The system here is:

```
gcc: 7.0.3
boost: 1.65.1
libc6: 2.73
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build command is in the wrong order, and order matters.

GCC reads left-to-right, taking symbols from libraries when it already knows it needs them. As you put `program.cpp` last, you don't make that known until all listed libraries have already been identified and discarded.

**Put `program.cpp` *first*, then the libraries it needs.**

```
g++ -o program program.cpp -lboost_filesystem -ldl -lboost_system
```

Yes, it's kind of weird. (Even weirder that it worked on Debian! Though apparently only some "recent" Linuxy distributions default `--as-needed` on, which is what causes the behaviour you see, showing that the behaviour isn't necessarily guaranteed. Perhaps Debian 9 just outright does not do that.)

---

More info:

- [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45135/560648)

Comment: Thank you, I had found information about the sometimes important order of linker flags, but never tought about the fact, that the source might matter just as well.